# What does ~\epsilon means in the Bellman equation?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Slide 30 of [these lecture notes](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture14.pdf) for reinforcement learning contains this "Bellman equation":

$$ Q^*(s, a) = \mathbb{E}_{s'\sim\varepsilon} \left[ r + \gamma \max_{a'} Q^*(s', a') \mid s, a \right]$$

Everything else makes sense to me, but what does the "$\sim\varepsilon$" part mean?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41306/232706.  But I don't find any definition for $\varepsilon$ in the earlier slides, and I'm not familiar enough with the equation to say from personal knowledge.  It should mean something about "next state" and transition probabilities??

Comment: It means that $s'$ is distributed as $\epsilon$, ie: the values $s'$ are taken from $\epsilon$. However, there's no definition of $\epsilon$ in the slides you provided, so it's difficult to know what it means. Maybe it's a standard notation in RL, can you provide more context?

Comment: I assume the definition of epsilon is kind of implicit. That helped me thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an $\epsilon$, but an $\mathcal{E}$, which probably stands for environment. The more common notation in RL is

$$Q^*(s,a)=\mathbb{E}_{s'\sim p(\cdot\mid s,a)}[r(s,a)+\gamma \max_{a'}Q^*(s',a')\mid s,a]. $$

What it means is that we take action $a$ in state $s$. Then, the environment returns a state $s'$. So, it is an expectation over all possible new states, when taking action $a$ in state $s$.

Answer (score -1):

Symbolizes the expected error.

Comment: Some kind of justification would make this kind of short answer better.  But in this case, I also think this is wrong: see [my comment](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/112457/what-does-epsilon-means-in-the-bellman-equation/112477#comment113899_112457) on the Question.